# CALL MULTIPLY Function in Assembler

Tags: function, assembly, calling-convention, function-call, intel-8080

so i have a small practika in a couple of hours and im nearly done with preparations. Theres one task i dont really understand tho.

The task:

> For further processing, measured values m (0 ≤ m ≤ 255) are stored in
>   memory starting at address 0x81. The number n of measured values to be
>   processed is at address 0x80 (1 ≤ n ≤ 15). Write an EVALUATION program
>   in which the value 310 is multiplied for each measured value and then
>   the value 510 is added. The calculated measured values should be
>   written back to the same memory locations. To realize the
>   multiplication, the program MULTIPLY from the previous task is to be
>   called up as a subprogram. To return from the subprogram to the main
>   program, the subprogram must be terminated with the RET instruction.
>   Make sure that no relevant data is lost in the main program when you
>   call the subroutine. The stack can be used to save data. The main
>   program should start with address 0x60, the subprogram with 0x40.
>   Enter the program into the table!
>
> [image: The Table]

And my programm MULTIPLY i have to call.

[image: multy][image: multy2]

i really only need to know how to implement a new function, call this one and return without losing my values. i already checked my function in a simulator and it works so no worries here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What architecture is this?  I think 8085 based on the opcode for `mvi a`

Comment: i think its i8080, hex code for return is C9...i just dont really know how to write it down, do i write it like 0x60, 0x61 - 0xCD Multiply - CALL MULTIPLY - calls funktion multiply and then where is the return and how do i save values when returning

Comment: Looks like 8080 (or 8080 subset of one of its successors).  Except: `LXI SP` is a 3 byte instruction, as is `JMP` and `JZ`.  I guess the `H` register is zeroized somewhere else ?  The `JMP 0x12` seems to be jumping to a `POP` with no balancing `PUSH`.  I cannot figure out what this code is doing (or is supposed to do).  `CALL`/`RET` is the usual way to invoke and return from a subroutine.  I suggest passing arguments and receiving return value(s) in registers.  The subroutine can, of course, save and restore registers which the caller may want to use.